# Javascript/JQuery loop through array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, delay, slidetoggle

I'm trying to show/hide sponsor logos on my site, show/hide one after the other endlessly. I think I'm kinda close, but after banging my head, I decided it was time for help. Here's my code:

```
var sponsors = ["prointec","pequigraf"];
for (var i = 0; i < sponsors.length; i++){
    setTimeout($(document.getElementById(sponsors[i])).slideToggle("slow", "swing"), 1000);
    setTimeout($(document.getElementById(sponsors[i])).slideToggle("slow", "swing"), 10000 * (i + 1));
}
```

Basically, it should show one AFTER the other (after 10 seconds), but instead, runs all at once. Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are people downvoting this question??? If you don't feel comfortable with reading / answering beginner's stuff just ignore it. Seems like some people at SO see newbie questions as playground for bashing exclusively.

Comment: Just in case anyone wants to check how this looks (or if anyone wants to use this simple but yet effective code), here's the implementation of it (it's a black bar underneath the hero image): http://www.oficiografico.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the timeout a function reference. Also you should be nesting your timeouts. Try to think asynchronously when writing JavaScript.

I haven't tested this, but this is what I came up with. Also note that 10 seconds is 10,000 milliseconds, not 1000.

```
var sponsors = ["prointec","pequigraf"];

var i = 0;

$(document.getElementById(sponsors[0])).show();
$(document.getElementById(sponsors[1])).hide();

var toggleSponsor = function() {
    $(document.getElementById(sponsors[i])).hide();

    i = (i + 1) % sponsors.length;
    $(document.getElementById(sponsors[i])).show();

    setTimeout(toggleSponsor, 10000);
};

setTimeout(toggleSponsor, 10000);
```

Comment: That was neat! Works like charm! Thanks a million times!

Comment: You're welcome. If you would like me to explain any part of the code please just ask.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this as an answer instead of a comment just to make sure I can do some proper code formatting.

rpamely's code looks like just what you need, but you can simplify it quite a bit. Just prefix your two sponsor IDs with '#' and you can remove all the `document.getElementById()` calls:

```
var sponsors = [ "#prointec","#pequigraf" ];

var i = 0;

$(sponsors[0]).show();
$(sponsors[1]).hide();

var toggleSponsor = function() {
    $(sponsors[i]).hide();

    i = (i + 1) % sponsors.length;
    $(sponsors[i]).show();

    setTimeout(toggleSponsor, 10000);
};

setTimeout(toggleSponsor, 10000);
```